# Spline parameter (factor) and instance on curve (No influence)

Tags: bezier-curves, transforms, geometry-nodes

I use the *Factor* value of the curve to set the scaling for instances. This also works well.

But when I use the node `Translate Instances` in the next step to change the position of the instances, it does not work as expected.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try using capture node after instance on points for spline parameter factor and plug this output to your map range

Comment: @Chris, maybe, I don't understand, but it's don't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following answers your question:

[image]

As @Chris already noted: You have to capture the value for *Factor* with `Capture Attribute` before.

...However, I don't understand what exactly you want to do with it, because the transformation of the instances makes little sense even this way visually. But this is just my opinion.

If you move the positions of the individual instances, you can only move them on the local or global axis, and thus actually lose the reference to your curve on which you have instantiated the objects.

Maybe the node `Rotate Instances` which is fed with a random value will help you instead...

[image]

Comment: I only need the offset. The vine is thicker at the beginning than at the end and I need to lift the leaves a little so that they are on the surface of the vine.

Comment: @IgorYukhimenko ...Then I would rather recommend you to do the move with the node `Transform` before the instantiation, as you can see here in my example.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using transform node before instancing. In this case, you don't need to use Capture attribute and leaf offset scales automatically with object scale and offset direction is always relative to leaf.

[image]

Comment: It will not work.
Sheet offsets must be different from what part of the curve they are on.

Comment: Aren't they related to the scale?