# How to control Instances' size and rotation along curve?

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I have this curve in geometry nodes. I have the triangles along the curve in random positions.

- I'd like the instances to be aligned on the mesh normals with their Z axis.
- I also would like the instances Z-axis rotation (the base of all the triangles)
  to be aligned parallel along the curve's longitudinal axis.
- I'd like the size of the triangles to change along the curve (bigger where the curve is thick and smaller where the curve is thin)
- As a bonus is it possible to have them not to collide with each other? With ray-cast
  perhaps?

Tried with ChatGPT but it keeps on giving me crazy solutions. :/

Greatly appreciate your help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/271052

Comment: @quellenform Thx! I copied the one in the other post, the instances are perfectly aligned, but now I face 2 problems:

Comment: @quellenform The curve's thickness can't be modified in GN and the random rotation (tilt) of the instances along the curve's axis is also missing.